# getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream

Tags: java, file-io, web-applications, fileinputstream

I was trying to load a file in a webapp, and I was getting a `FileNotFound` exception when I used `FileInputStream`. However, using the same path, I was able to load the file when I did `getResourceAsStream()`. 
What is the difference between the two methods, and why does one work while the other doesn't?

Answer (score 263, accepted):

The [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and consorts acts on the local disk file system. The root cause of your problem is that *relative* paths in `java.io` are dependent on the current working directory. I.e. the directory from which the JVM (in your case: the webserver's one) is started. This may for example be `C:\Tomcat\bin` or something entirely different, but thus *not* `C:\Tomcat\webapps\contextname` or whatever you'd expect it to be. In a normal Eclipse project, that would be `C:\Eclipse\workspace\projectname`. You can learn about the current working directory the following way:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

However, the working directory is in no way programmatically controllable. You should really prefer using *absolute* paths in the `File` API instead of relative paths. E.g. `C:\full\path\to\file.ext`.

You don't want to hardcode or guess the absolute path in Java (web)applications. That's only portability trouble (i.e. it runs in system X, but not in system Y). The normal practice is to place those kind of resources in the **classpath**, or to add its full path to the classpath (in an IDE like Eclipse that's the `src` folder and the "build path" respectively). This way you can grab them with help of the `ClassLoader` by  [`ClassLoader#getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) or [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-). It is able to locate files relative to the "root" of the classpath, as you by coincidence figured out. In webapplications (or any other application which uses multiple classloaders) it's recommend to use the `ClassLoader` as returned by `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` for this so you can look "outside" the webapp context as well.

Another alternative in webapps is the [`ServletContext#getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) and its counterpart [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-). It is able to access files located in the public `web` folder of the webapp project, including the `/WEB-INF` folder. The `ServletContext` is available in servlets by the inherited [`getServletContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext--) method, you can call it as-is.

#### See also:

- [Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application)
- [What does servletcontext.getRealPath("/") mean and when should I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-servletcontext-getrealpath-mean-and-when-should-i-use-it)
- [Recommended way to save uploaded files in a servlet application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application)
- [How to save generated file temporarily in servlet based web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255366/java-io-filenotfoundexception-when-trying-to-save-generated-file-in-web-applicat)

Comment: @khylo: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952090/accessing-i18n-properties-file-in-a-jsf-application-programmatically/7955826#7955826

Answer (score 31):

`getResourceAsStream` is the right way to do it for web apps (as you already learned).

The reason is that reading from the file system cannot work if you package your web app in a WAR.  This is the proper way to package a web app.  It's portable that way, because you aren't dependent on an absolute file path or the location where your app server is installed.

Comment: +1 - though "cannot work" is too strong.  (Reading from the filesystem can be made to work, but doing it portably is a tricky ... and a lot more code, especially if the resource is in a JAR.)

Comment: duffy, very nice answer and you explained what my mistake was, but BalusC went into a lot of detail - I think his answer would be helpful for people who'd like to know the inner details as well. Hope you don't mind me changing the accepted answer to his!

Comment: @Stephen - I don't think "cannot work" is too strong.  Even something as simple as being deployed on two different servers with different paths to the app server will break it.  The point is that you need to make your WAR as self-contained as possible.  Your point is correct, but I'm going to stick to my wording.

Answer (score 16):

FileInputStream will load a the file path you pass to the constructor as relative from the *working directory* of the Java process. Usually in a web container, this is something like the `bin` folder.

`getResourceAsStream()` will load a file path relative [from your application's classpath](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 14):

The `FileInputStream` class works directly with the underlying file system. If the file in question is not physically present there, it will fail to open it. The `getResourceAsStream()` method works differently. It tries to locate and load the resource using the `ClassLoader` of the class it is called on. This enables it to find, for example, resources embedded into `jar` files.

Comment: Well, files within a jar are still physically "present" in a file system, just contained within other files

Comment: Well, yes, of course. But they are usually not something seen as independent entities in the file system, unless you application happens to know about the `jar` file format and its implications. And in Java, the appropriate `ClassLoader` might have this knowledge, whereas a plain `FileInputStream` certainly has not.

Answer (score 8):

classname.getResourceAsStream() loads a file via the classloader of classname. If the class came from a jar file, that is where the resource will be loaded from.

FileInputStream is used to read a file from the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

I am here by separating both the usages by marking them as File Read(java.io) and Resource Read(ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()).

**File Read -** 
1. Works on local file system. 
2. Tries to locate the file requested from current JVM launched directory as root 
3. Ideally good when using files for processing in a pre-determined location like,/dev/files or C:\Data.

**Resource Read -**
1. Works on class path 
2. Tries to locate the file/resource in current or parent classloader classpath. 
3. Ideally good when trying to load files from packaged files like war or jar.