# Java IO file dependency

Tags: java, java-io

Created small Java application using Netbeans IDE.
In package cntp is my source file from which i load neural network:

```
NeuralNetwork myNeuralNetwork = NeuralNetwork.load("src\\nwork\\nfile.nnet");
```

This static method has 2 overloads:

`public static NeuralNetwork load(String filePath);

public static NeuralNetwork load(InputStream inputStream);`

I placed file nfile.nnet in **nwork package**.

Everything works when i run application from Netbeans but when i copy the content of "dist"
folder somewhere else and execute jar it doesn't find the dependent nfile.nnet.
So i need the way to make my application path portable. How to achieve this?

Solution thx to @RC and @Aaron Digulla from referenced post:
`InputStream is=ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/nwork/nfile.nnet");
        NeuralNetwork myNeuralNetwork = NeuralNetwork.load(is);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use resources. see [Getting the inputstream from a classpath resource (XML file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793213/getting-the-inputstream-from-a-classpath-resource-xml-file)