# Pathway for .jar files

Tags: java, path, jar

I am creating a game as a project and I have gone through the code and debugged it. The problem I'm having is making a jar run with the code. I know that the error is the pathway to the images are wrong when I export it as a runnable jar file (exported using eclipse) but I don't know what the pathway would be to put in my `ImageIO.read(new File("pathway/filename.jpg"));`

Comment: You should be loading the images as resources, not as files.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the question, but i think you're looking for ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793213/getting-the-inputstream-from-a-classpath-resource-xml-file

Answer (score 2):

See ["Accessing Resources"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) from the documentation.

You want some variant of [`ClassLoader.getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29), though whether you access via the classloader or the class depends on how you want to package things.  Here's what I usually do:

```
InputStream resourceStream 
                  = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/pathway/in/jar/filename.jpg");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(resourceStream);
```

Comment: For in/jar do you literally say in/jar or like in/"jarname.extension" ?

Comment: If the path within the jar was "/images/filename.jpg", then I would use that as the argument.

Comment: Ok thanks, this is my 2nd year of java and haven't gotten very far past my schools subset.