# Expand WAR or EAR files in jBoss AS 7

Tags: deployment, jboss, war, ear, jboss7.x

I'm deploying a WebService project into a jBoss AS7, and everything goes OK except that jBoss doesn't expand my WAR or EAR file.

Already tried copying the file to the "jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments" folder and using the WebConsole, but in both cases the result was the same.

If I deploy from within Eclipse everything runs OK.

I need it to expand my file because in the application initialization I scan the class 
directories looking for the correct class to instantiate using reflection.

**EDIT :** Don't know if this a particular situation with jBoss AS 7 or with the jBoss AS family, because I already used WebSphere and jBoss Web and both of them expanded the files.

**EDIT2 :** Added a System.out with the execution path

```
MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

and it returns the following path

```
C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\bin\content\ServerEAR.ear\Server.war\WEB-INF\classes
```

witch doesn't exist. So I did a search for the class name and fount it at

```
C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\deployment5a9e98d5c43716c3\Server.war-e31a657d2bc3bd0f\WEB-INF\classes\r30
```

Isn't it possible to force JBoss to extract the files to the deployment folder? Or how can I get the previous path at run time.

Comment: Is deploying in exploded form an option ?

Comment: By exploded form you mean decompress the WAR file manually and place it in the deployment folder? If yes, no. It's not an option :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had forgotten about this question, so this is the way that I solved it:

```
public String getRealFilePath(String aFilePath) throws Exception
{
    org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile vFile = org.jboss.vfs.VFS.getChild(aFilePath);
    URI fileNameDecodedTmp = org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.getPhysicalURI(vFile);

    path = fileNameDecodedTmp.getPath();
    System.out.println(path);
    return path;
}
```

So at runtime I just need to call getRealFilePath() with the original question values, and problem solved ;)

Comment: I didn't know anything about the virtual file system that JBoss uses. I just noted that loading files with  `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource()` led to a directory in `JBOSS_HOME/bin/content` instead of the expected `JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments/<myWarFile.war>`. 
However this seems to work. So thanks a lot for sharing this! I'm only a little concerned about the JBoss dependency that I catching when using classes from the `vfs` packages.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you cannot force Jboss7 to auto expand the `war` file when deploying.

You can, however, copy the already expanded `war` and you shouldn't have any problems.

Actually, if you look closely at the Eclipse deployment, you will notice that it copies the whole **directory**  to the deployment directory, not the `war` file itself.

Why do you need to deploy exploded, by the way? If you need to access and read some files as resources, you can have a look at [classpath resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793213/getting-the-inputstream-from-a-classpath-resource-xml-file)

Answer (score 2):

Please check you classpath setting. I faced the same problem recently, and solved it by added system environment variables:

```
CLASSPATH=.;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\lib;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\lib\tools.jar;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\lib\dt.jar; `
```