# Executable .jar fails to start because of .properties file loading

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, properties-file

I have the problem running executable .jar file. I've created a project which contains a .properties file. It works just fine when I start it from eclipse, but when I export it to executable .jar file and try to run it with:

```
java -jar myfile.jar
```

I get the following exception:

(couldn't post image here)
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/824/29583616.png/

I've checked my manifest file in the .jar and it contains the

```
Class-Path: .
```

And here's the properties file loading:

```
properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(
            "src/com/resources/treeView.properties"));
```

Any idea what causes this exception?

Comment: try "properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(
            "/com/resources/treeView.properties"));" without "src" in path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the properties file is inside the jar file, you cannot access it as a file.

You need to ask the classloader to get the resource as an inputstream.  See [Getting the inputstream from a classpath resource (XML file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793213/getting-the-inputstream-from-a-classpath-resource-xml-file)

Comment: Thanks! That worked!

properties.load(ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/resources/treeView.properties"));

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse (and in most IDEs) the current directory is the project's root directory. This means that `Class-Path: .` means something else in Eclipse than when you run it from the command line. This is why you wrote "src/com/...". Remove "src":

```
properties.load(new FileInputStream("com/resources/treeView.properties"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your properties file is within JAR file. So, use : **ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream().**