# Obtaining an input stream from a classpath file

Tags: java, android, maven, intellij-idea

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793213/getting-the-inputstream-from-a-classpath-resource-xml-file) question, I have tried the following when reading a file from the classpath of a maven project built with IntelliJ:

```
public class testTemplateManager {

private TemplateManager templateManager;
private String m_includePath;

public void createTemplateManager() {
    String relativePath = "/src/main/java/com/eprosima/templates";
    String fileName = "idlTypes.stg";
    String filePath = relativePath + "/" + fileName;
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream res = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(var4);
    if(res == null) {
        classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        res = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(var4);
    }

    if(res != null) {
        return new BufferedReader(getInputStreamReader(res));
    }
}
```

The resource **res** is always null regardless of the **relativePath**(relative to the project root directory). I have tried to use the following paths with the same outcome:

```
String relativePath = "src/main/java/com/eprosima/templates";
String relativePath = "src/main/java/com.eprosima/templates";
```

The classpath looks like:

[image]

I need to read the template files located in **/src/main/java/com/eprosima/templates**.

Answer (score 1):

```
String relativePath = "/src/main/java/com/eprosima/templates";
```

The problem is here. `src/main/java` is not part of your classpath. It's not there in any way at runtime. It should be

```
String relativePath = "/com/eprosima/templates";
```

Comment: The output is still the same. res always remains null.

Comment: Try it without the leading /.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
String relativePath = "./src/main/java/com/eprosima/templates";
```

For example I have project that has package com.example.main. In that package I have "FileTest.java" with following code:

```
package com.example.main;
```

import java.io.File;

public class FileTest {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("./src/com/example/main/FileTest.java");
    if (file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("existed!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not exists!");
    }
}
```

}

then run this file output prints "existed!"

Hope this help!

Comment: It won't. The src directory won't be there at runtime, outside the IDE.