# Unable to find the file specified java (maven configuration)

Tags: java, maven, file, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to refer to a file inside a maven project structure. Through my test cases the file is located successfully, but when I deploy the project to a weblogic environment, I am receiving an error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   keystore.jks (The system cannot
>   find the path specified)

In my code I am referring to the file as follow:

```
File pKeyFile = new File("certificates/keystore.jks");
String pKeyPassword = keyStorePassword;
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(pKeyFile);
```

Update:

I tried the following:

```
File pKeyFile = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("certificates/keystore.jks").toString());
        String pKeyPassword = keyStorePassword;
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(pKeyFile);
        keyStore.load(keyInput, pKeyPassword.toCharArray());
        keyInput.close();
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, pKeyPassword.toCharArray());
```

When I evaluated the this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("certificates/keystore.jks") expression, I could see that the file was found. But it still threw the same error when it tried to load the file as an InputStream.

Comment: You should use "certificates/keystore.jks"

Comment: My apologies. That was just a test I ran, I updated the question.

Comment: Take a look on this page: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/. You should use something like `File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());` where class loader is `ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();`

Comment: Hi @MichałZiober I am using the ClassLoader example and I can see that the file is retrieved, but when I load it into a FileInputStream it still returns the same error, do you perhaps have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write

```
File pKeyFile = new File("src/main/resources/certificates/keystore.jks");
```

In Java paths are either:

1. Absolute
2. Relative: that's your case
3. Classpath resources

A relative path starts from the location where your program is run. So using src/ is definitely wrong

Comment: Do you perhaps know how I can use the file using classpath resources ? I see the file is generated under target/classes/certificates/keystore.jks

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793213/getting-the-inputstream-from-a-classpath-resource-xml-file