# How to convert scala.io.BufferedSource to java.io.File?

Tags: java, scala, apache-poi

I want to use the Apache POI library in a Scala project.

How can I convert a `scala.io.BufferedSource` type to a `java.io.File` type?

```
  val file = Source.fromResource("resource.file") // is type scala.io.BufferedSource
  // how can I do the conversion here
  val workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file) // requires type java.io.File
```

This works, but I want to avoid specifying the folder path since the folder structure is handled by sbt convention:

```
  val file = new File("src/main/resources/resource.file")
  val workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file)
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Use the version that reads from an `InputStream`: http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create-java.io.InputStream- and check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793213/getting-the-inputstream-from-a-classpath-resource-xml-file

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I was not able to get an input stream using any of the below statements:
Using(Source.fromFile("resource.file")) { source => source.mkString }

Comment: val file = getClass.getResourceAsStream("resource.file")

Comment: val file = ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("resource.file")

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar enough with Scala and Java to fill in the missing pieces...

Comment: You could consider https://github.com/norbert-radyk/spoiwo

Comment: @Zhao - Scala supports all the Java classes - you can just create a java.io.FileInputStream if that better suits using POI - you don't have to use scala.io.BufferedSource

Comment: Thanks @PJFanning.  I wanted to avoid specifying the folder path `src/main/resources/` and thought `scala.io.Source` would be a better fit.  But now I'm regretting going down that path.

Comment: @ZhaoLi `val file = getClass.getResourceAsStream("resource.file")` should return an `InputStream` and if you look at the [`Source` code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.7/src/library/scala/io/Source.scala#L180) you will see that it does something very similar. If you please the whole exact code should be: `val file = Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("resource.file")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the folder structure is not handled by `sbt`.

What happens is that the contents of `src/main/resources` are shipped into the JAR and are available in your classpath as a resource.

If you do something along the lines of what `Source.fromResource` does, you should be able to get what you need.

Here is the code snippet for reference:

```
  /** Reads data from a classpath resource, using either a context classloader (default) or a passed one.
   *
   *  @param  resource     name of the resource to load from the classpath
   *  @param  classLoader  classloader to be used, or context classloader if not specified
   *  @return              the buffered source
   */
  def fromResource(resource: String, classLoader: ClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())(implicit codec: Codec): BufferedSource =
    Option(classLoader.getResourceAsStream(resource)) match {
      case Some(in) => fromInputStream(in)
      case None     => throw new FileNotFoundException(s"resource '$resource' was not found in the classpath from the given classloader.")
    }
```

This code is found on GitHub and here is the link for a recent `HEAD`: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/8a2cf63ee5bad8c8c054f76464de0e10226516a0/src/library/scala/io/Source.scala#L174-L184

In principle, you can load the resource as a stream using the Java API and pass it to the `WorkbookFactory.create` static method overload that takes an `InputStream` as an input that someone mentioned in a comment.

Something along the lines of

```
def maybeResourceAt(path: String): Option[InputStream] =
  Option(
    Thread.
      currentThread().
      getContextClassLoader().
      getResourceAsStream(path)
  )

val input = maybeResourceAt("resource.file").getOrElse(sys.error("oh noes"))
val workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(input)
```

should get the job done.

I'm not sure who's in charge of closing the `InputStream`. Intuitively I would say that `create` should consume it entirely but double check with the library's documentation to be sure.

Comment: Thank you for writing all of that out. 

Comment: Happy to help! :-)